# when spawning airodump-ng via node the output is truncated to 80 chars per column

Tags: node.js, aircrack-ng

I have a simple code that tries to read and parse airodump-ng output.
When I try to do the following:

```
const proc = require('child_process');
child = proc.spawn('airodump-ng', ['mon0']);

child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```

The output is truncated and I am getting only 80 chars even when the window is at max size.
I am working on ubuntu 16.04 with node 7.2.0.

I would like the output to not be truncated so that I can capture the entire essid name and not just the first 5 chars of the essid.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I figured out the problem.
I used the aircrack-ng suite from the ubuntu package-manager. It is an old version that has this bug.
I compiled the src from github and I am no longer getting the truncated output.